# Exporting post metrics from Social Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud

Does anyone know how to export these data points from within social studio? I can run the report on these posts, but I can't find a way to get all of these metrics on an export.

[image: i]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to locate a report that can export this data, but it is available via Social Studio API.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_social.meta/api_social/1-retrieve-imported-content.htm?search_text=engagement

> **Retrieve Posts & Metrics**
>   This method retrieves posts and their metrics imported to a workspace.